# SharedPreferences within a fragment

Tags: android-fragments, sharedpreferences

Once the user selects an item from a list in another fragment it brings you to this fragment. And I'm having issues trying to save the users rating that was selected.  when the user goes back it should be the same rating that was previously selected.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class infoFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView degrees;
    ImageView image;
    String stringtext;
    String [] hold;
    private RatingBar rating;
    SharedPreferences wmbPreference1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

why can i not use "this"

```
rating =((RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)).setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
            wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            degrees =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }

    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                            boolean fromTouch) {
        final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
        editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
        editor.putInt("numStars", numStars);
        editor.commit();
        int ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", 0);
    }
    public void setText(final String string) {
       Character[] hold;
        if(string == "apple"){
            String[] word = { " A \n", "B\n" };

            degrees.setText(Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));;
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.APPLE);
        }
```

Should I call onRatingChanged within the conditional statement for it to save?

```
        if(string == "orange"){
            String[] word = { " AA\n", "AB\n" };
            degrees.setText(Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));;
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bruce);
        }

    }

    public void sentText(){
        new MyTask().execute();

    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Bundle b = getArguments();
            stringtext = b.getString("text");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){setText(stringtext);
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Fragment` should implement `OnRatingBarChangeListener`:

```
public class infoFragment extends Fragment implements OnRatingBarChangeListener
```

---

The other thing is that `setOnRatingChangeListener` does not return a value, so you can't assign the return value to `rating` as you did.

You should do:

```
rating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar); 
rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks , sorry to get back so late. so the error went away but my ratings are not being saved.  withing each conditional statement i call the method onRatingChange().  so once i give the item a rating..i hit the back button and re click on the item but the rating is set back to the default.

Comment: Please post a new question and I can try to help you